# Do commands continue running if a remote terminal is disconnected?

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, gnome-terminal, putty

I seem unable to find a clear answer, so I figured on asking a clear question instead (well, technically it's two questions, but they are similar).

If I'm using remote terminal from another machine on the network (a non linux machine, but I think that would be academic), or indeed from outside the network when I terminal from my phone (again, not sure it would matter, but just in case...) and I start a long process and the connection becomes broken (let's say the cat sits on the keyboard and closes putty; or cell service drops; or the other cat is playing with the flashing light on the power bar and manages to turn the router off); both ends of the connection are still active, just no longer connected...

Q1) If I'm running a normal command like `rsync` (but not limited to) and it was incomplete, does the command continue to run on the server?

Q2) If I'm running a bash executable, which again was incomplete, does the command continue to run on the server?

I know I can reconnect and just run things again, but not everything is as handy as `rsync` when it comes to resuming; and if it's a bash file running, it would take investigation to figure out how far it got.  The processes I'm using are primarily file manipulation; but are not limited to them (just in case that matters)

Comment: can this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection

Comment: They usually don't.